# How to create OTP input component in React JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create one otp component like the following.

[image: otp]

I am able to create one component like the following

[image: otp2]

But not able to achieve the initial `-` value in the input field. I want to show the initial value as `-` and also I need to update it based on the value we are entering. The code that I have done so far is as follows.

**OTP.js**

```
const [otpValues, setOtpValues] = useState(['', '', '', '', '', '']);
const otpFieldsRef = useRef([]);

const handleInput = (index, value) => {
if (value.length > 1) {
  return;
}
const newOtpValues = [...otpValues];
newOtpValues[index] = value;
setOtpValues(newOtpValues);
if (value.length === 1 && index < otpValues.length - 1) {
  otpFieldsRef.current[index + 1].focus();
}
const optVal = newOtpValues.join('');
onChange(optVal);
};

const handleBackspace = (index) => {
if (otpValues[index] !== '') {
  const newOtpValues = [...otpValues];
  newOtpValues[index] = '';
  setOtpValues(newOtpValues);
} else if (index > 0) {
  otpFieldsRef.current[index - 1].focus();
}
};

 return (

    {otpValues.map((value, index) => (
      <InputStyled
        name="otp1"
        type="text"
        autoComplete="off"
        className="text-center"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => handleInput(index, e.target.value)}
        onKeyDown={(e) => {
          if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
            handleBackspace(index);
          }
        }}
        ref={(ref) => {
          otpFieldsRef.current[index] = ref;
        }}
        tabIndex="1"
        maxLength="1"
        key={index}
        onInput={onInput}
        autofocus
      />
    ))}
    ....
```

When I add the initial value as `-` within useState I am not able to achieve the desired output. Please help to find a solution. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try placeholder and change the color. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_placeholder.asp